# How I can customize fbox and hrule?

Tags: macros, rules, examples, exercises

I want to customization a sample exercises for a book. I like so much this style:

[image: example style]

I think that is possible with `fbox` and `hrule`, but I don't know how I can do it. No need to use `fbox` and `hrule` if there is another way to do.

EDIT: The bottom rule is here [Creating a custom rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148761/creating-a-custom-rule?lq=1)

UPDATE: I have made my example code with the help Dan and azetina. Thank you both and now I share the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
% 1. define its color
\definecolor{ejemplo}{RGB}{37,153,116}
% 2. define its counter, to be reset with each section
\newcounter{ejemplo}[section]
\renewcommand\theejemplo{\mdseries\normalsize\thesection.\arabic{ejemplo}}
% 3. define the environment. Its argument is the name of the example.
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ejemplo}[1]{%
    \bigbreak
    \refstepcounter{ejemplo}
    \par%
% (a) heading
    \noindent{\color{ejemplo}\large\sffamily
    {\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}%
    \hline
        \cellcolor{ejemplo}\color{white}%
        \textmd{\normalsize Ejemplo} \theejemplo&\bfseries #1%
    \end{tabular}}}\par
% (b) space after and no indentation after
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \vspace{1em}%
        \@afterindentfalse
        \@afterheading
}   {\end{multicols}
% (c) place the custom rule
    \noindent{\color{ejemplo}%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \hrulefill\rule{2em}{0.4em}}%
    }\par%
    }
% The solution
\newcommand\solucion{
    \par\vspace{1em}
    \noindent
    \colorbox{ejemplo}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\sffamily\mdseries\color{white}Soluci\'on}}}%
    \par\vspace{1em}
    \@afterindentfalse
    \@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

And here the result:

[image: example]

Comment: Do you want to create an environment to replicate the example in the diagram or just the title of each example?

Comment: @azetina - I only want the title and footer, but if is possible all environment... I really appreciate it

Comment: Have you contemplated on using TikZ?

Comment: @azetina - No, but if with TikZ is possible I will use it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Ejemplo part looks like it was set with `colortbl` and the Soluci\'on part with `\colorbox` Here is some code to produce those effects. Normally one would code examples with `\newtheorem` and one would have to go to some effort to make this automatic. But it is late, and I will leave that until later (or someone else can step in). I didn't try to match the color and just went with blue. One can, of course change colors, fonts, and sizes to suit ones tastes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
Some text.

\bigskip
\noindent{\color{blue}\Large\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ll@{}}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue}\color{white}Ejemplo 37.12&\bfseries Choque Relativista
\end{tabular}}

\bigskip
Statement of example.

\bigskip
\noindent \colorbox{blue}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}SOLUCI\'ON}

\bigskip
Description of solution.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Here's a more complete example, coded as an `ejemplo` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1cm}
%
% Prepare an ejemplo environment
% 1. define its color
\definecolor{ejemplo}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.4}
% 2. define its counter, to be reset with each section
\newcounter{ejemplo}[section]
\renewcommand\theejemplo{\thesection.\arabic{ejemplo}}
% 3. Define the lengths of the rule that follows
\newlength\ejemplorulei
\newlength\ejemploruleii
\setlength\ejemploruleii{4em}
\setlength\ejemplorulei\textwidth
\addtolength\ejemplorulei{-\ejemploruleii}
% 4. define the environment. Its argument is the name of the
%    example.
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{ejemplo}[1]
{%
  \refstepcounter{ejemplo}
  \begin{multicols}{2}%
  %    (a) heading
  \noindent{\color{ejemplo}\large\sffamily
  \begin{tabular}{ll@{}}%
  \hline
    \cellcolor{ejemplo}\color{white}Ejemplo \theejemplo&\bfseries #1%
  \end{tabular}}\par
  %    (b) space after and no indentation after
  \vspace{1em}%
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}{\end{multicols}
  %    (c) place the custom rule
  \noindent{\color{ejemplo}%
  \rule[2ex]{\ejemplorulei}{.4pt}%
  \rule[2ex]{\ejemploruleii}{1.2pt}}\par
}
\newcommand\solucion{% The solution
  \par\vspace{1em}
  \noindent
  \colorbox{ejemplo}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{white}SOLUCI\'ON}%
  \par\vspace{1em}
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Start of section}
\blindtext
\begin{ejemplo}{Choque Relativista}
\blindtext[1]
\solucion
  \blindtext[2]
\end{ejemplo}

\end{document}
```

[image: more complete ejemplo]

Comment: It looks good! Just missing the bottom but I do not know how to do the lower right box. If possible make the example in two columns?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even see the line at the bottom. It's just two rules. I'll be adding a more-or-less complete solution in a bit