# Creating a custom rule

Tags: macros

Upon trying to answer, [How I can customize fbox and hrule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148658/10898) , I tried to do it using basic LaTeX commands as shown in the MWE below. But for some reason or the other the command `\egline` does not generate the same output as `\sampleline`. Why is that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\egline}{%
    \par\vskip 1ex%
    {\color{ejemplo}%
    \leavevmode\hrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax \hrule height 0.5ex width 2em%
    }%
    \par\vskip1ex%
    }
\definecolor{ejemplo}{RGB}{37,153,116}
\newcommand{\sampleline}{%
    \par\noindent%
    {\color{ejemplo}%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
        \hrulefill\rule{2em}{0.5ex}}%
        }%
    \par%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\egline
\sampleline
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

---

I redefined the command `\egline` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\egline}{%
    \par\vskip 1ex%
    {%
    \color{ejemplo}%
    \leavevmode%
    \vbox{%
    \hrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax}%
    \vbox{%
     \hrule height 0.5ex width 2em}%
    }%
    \par\vskip1ex%
    }
```

But it gives an extra white space (15pt horizontally)? Weird? See image below:

[image]

---

Doing a third definition following David Carlisle's suggestions, I have a poor man's fix to the above, but I still don't get what is causing the indentation.

```
\newcommand{\egline}{%
    \par\vskip 1ex%
    {%
    \color{ejemplo}%
    \hskip-15pt\leavevmode\vrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax\vrule height 0.5ex width 2em%
    }%
    \par\vskip1ex%
    }
```

---

To conclude, the fix is a `\noindent` where `\leavevmode` is:

```
\noindent\vrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax\vrule height 0.5ex width 2em%
```

Comment: Why are you using `\vskip 1ex` only on the first command?

Comment: @azetina - It was driving me crazy to do that. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Kiyoshi You are welcome but I am still working on a robust environment with referable counters, and stuff like that. If you do manage to construct your environment, you should post it

Comment: @azetina - Of course.

Comment: In your updated version you have made boxes and by default they are spaced to baselineskip, uou can use `\nointerlineskip` but you don't need a box, use `\nointerlineskip\leavevmode\vrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax\vrule height 0.5ex width 2em\par`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does not seem to work....weird. The indentation seems to be persistent, though your example above does what you were explaining.

Comment: @azetina got to go will look later if no one else answered

Comment: @azetina oh horizontal 15pt that is paragraph indent, use `\noindent` instead of `\leavevmode`

Comment: Oh my my well that was a no brainer...got to admit am not good at this type of coding. Am still learning. Thanks for teaching me abou t the `\nointerlineskip` command.

Comment: @azetina - I update my question ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\egline}{%
    \par\vskip 1ex%
% here you are in vertical mode
    {%
%here you put a colour whatsit on the vertical list (best to avoid that if possible)
\color{ejemplo}%
% here you start a paragraph and get into horizontal mode

    \leavevmode
% \hrule isn't allowed in hmode, so this ends the (blank) paragraph and gets back to vmode
\hrule height 1pt width \dimexpr\hsize-2em\relax
% as we are in vmode this rule comes under the previous one
 \hrule height 0.5ex width 2em%
    }%
% another color whatsit gets inserted here (again on a vertical list)
    \par\vskip1ex%
    }
```

Comment: So one cannot put the second hrule beside the first?

Comment: @azetina in vertical mode no, in horizontal mode yes, but in hmode you want vrule not an hrule.

Comment: Could you exemplify, s'il vous plait

Comment: @azetina it's same as boxes if you go `\hbox{a}\hbox{b}` then in vertical mode the a is above the b, in horizontal mode the a is to the left of the b. In vertical mode rules stack one above the other, in horizontal mode they stack side by side.

Comment: See my updated question.